# How to display the length of the path traveled from point 1 to point 2?

Tags: geometry-nodes

In this case, the reference point seems to be at the origin of the coordinates of the world, but I want to get the length of the path that is sampled here:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

You can capture the length of the spline with `Sample Curve` by passing the spline length provided by `Spline Parameter` as *Value*.

This looks like this:

[image]

PS: If you use a NURBS curve, you would have to convert it at the very beginning with the node `Resample Curve`, otherwise you would always get the interpolated values inherent to the NURBS curve.

Comment: the countdown starts from 1.3
or I'm connecting
the wrong way, you can show the full chain

Comment: @1so Sorry, I don't understand this right now. ...that's the whole node tree. What exactly do you mean by "countdown"?

Comment: uploaded a screenshot, the point of reference 1.3

Comment: @1so Ah, now I understand what exactly you mean. This has to do with the fact that you are using a NURBS curve here. This doesn't work with this one, because the points are interpolated here. You would have to use a poly curve or a Bezier curve instead, or you use the node `Resample Curve` (set to *Evaluated*) at the very beginning.